# I can't use action groups anymore from version 2.9

Tags: opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I used a lot of action groups to manage permissions as groups and use them on roles that a user gets, After updating from version 2.8 to 2.11.1 and also 2.9 I cannot find my action groups on "index permissions" or "cluster permissions" sections does anyone know that is this feature got removed or not???

I've created an action group from Security>Permissions section and expect to find it while creating a role.

from version 2.9 and later action groups no longer show up in roles. this was working in version 2.8

to calrify more: in version 2.8 the action groups appear like below

[image]

I can't even find "kibana_all_read" action group in version 2.9 and above

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.